# python 2 module dependency on python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, autotest

For one of the test with avocado on power architecture, I am getting an error for a dependency module as:

> ERROR: No module named 'autotest'

I tried installing this module with pip and I am getting python 2 dependency error as below

```
 eck_version.py", line 58, in find_desired_python
         raise ValueError('Python 2.x version 2.4 or better is required')
     ValueError: Python 2.x version 2.4 or better is required
     ----------------------------------------
 WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/3c/733f2a67e63e894256d50c58d237c1b2df9906aba0c937500b2b72fa8b86/autotest-0.16.1.tar.gz#sha256=14834ebfa1d6818c52ae99324005d605832e2e62d0039eeb4f1b7ccf9be2aa20 (from https://pypi.org/simple/autotest/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement autotest (from versions: 0.16.1, 0.16.2, 0.16.3, 0.16.4)
 ERROR: No matching distribution found for autotest
```

Comment: Both `avocado` and `autotest` are Python 2 only. You will have to run everything on outdated Python 2 which implies using old version of pretty much everything, or drop `avocado`. I'd prefer the later.

Comment: I am able to run all avocado tests with python3. Only for 1 test alone getting a module dependency error and which doesn't seems to be available for python3.